# matAutocomplete is not setting the value to formcontrol on select from dropdown angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, angular-reactive-forms, mat-autocomplete

I have a component in which I am using Mat auto complete with google autocomplete apis

Here is the code

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, forwardRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api/api.service';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, finalize, switchMap, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { FormValidatorService } from '../../services/form-validator/form-validator.service';
import { LocationFormValue } from '../location-form/location-form.component';
import { AddressInfo } from "./../../../../../../../backend/src/models/address-info";

export interface AddressFormValue {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  location: LocationFormValue;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-form',
  templateUrl: './address-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressFormComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressFormComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AddressFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  componentName: string;

  @Input()
  public form: FormGroup;

  loadingMsg = "Search...";
  minLengthTerm = 3;
  addresses: AddressInfo[];

  public subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

  public constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private formValidator: FormValidatorService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    // this._buildForms();
    this._listenForFormValueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get("address1").valueChanges
      .pipe(
        filter(res => {
          return res !== null && res.length >= this.minLengthTerm
        }),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(1000),
        tap(() => {
          this.ref.markForCheck();
          this.addresses = [];
          this.loadingMsg = "Loading....";
        }),
        switchMap(value => this.apiService.getAddressSuggestions(value)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
              this.loadingMsg = null;
            }),
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log("file: address-form.component.ts ~ line 88 ~ AddressFormComponent ~ .subscribe ~ data", data);
        this.addresses = data;
        this.loadingMsg = null;
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      });
  }

  private _listenForFormValueChanges(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.form?.valueChanges?.subscribe(value => {
        console.log("file: address-form.component.ts ~ line 114 ~ AddressFormComponent ~ _listenForFormValueChanges ~ value", value);
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
      })
    );
  }

  onAddressSelected() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    const address1 = this.form.value.address1;

    this.form.get("address1").setValue(address1);
  }

  displayWith(value: any) {
    console.log("file: address-form.component.ts ~ line 123 ~ AddressFormComponent ~ displayWith ~ value", value);
    return value?.description;
  }

  public get value(): AddressFormValue {
    return this.form.value;
  }

  public set value(value: AddressFormValue) {
    console.log("file: address-form.component.ts ~ line 132 ~ AddressFormComponent ~ setvalue ~ value", value);
    this.form?.setValue(value);
    this.onChange();
    this.onTouched();
  }

  public onChange: any = () => {
  }

  public onTouched: any = () => {
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  public writeValue(obj: any): void {
    console.log("file: address-form.component.ts ~ line 150 ~ AddressFormComponent ~ writeValue ~ obj", obj);
    if (obj) {
      this.value = obj;
    }

    if (obj === null) {
      this.form.reset();
    }
  }

  public validate(_: FormControl): any {
    return this.form.valid ? null : { addressForm: { valid: false } };
  }

  public getError(controlName: string): string {
    return this.formValidator.getErrorMessage(controlName, this.form);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    try {
      this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => {
        if (sub) {
          sub.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
      this._onDestroy.next();
      this._onDestroy.complete();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    }
  }
}
```

and HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="form">


  <!-- ADDRESS LINE 1 AND ADDRESS LINE 2 -->
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="2.5%">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="100" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label>Address Line 1</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Address Line 1" [formControlName]="'address1'" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onAddressSelected()" [displayWith]="displayWith">
        <mat-option *ngIf="loadingMsg" class="is-loading">{{loadingMsg}}</mat-option>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!loadingMsg">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let address of addresses" [value]="address?.description">
            <span><b>{{address.description}}</b> ({{address.postcode}})</span>
          </mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <mat-error>Address Line 1 is {{this.getError('address1')}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

</div>
```

On search it shows the list of options, on select of any option it is not setting that value in the mat input, it remains empty, though the value is present in form object.

`onAddressSelected` i am manually setting the form's `address1` but still it is showing empty
Am i missing something?